# How am I to understand this notation with regards to bdS and the int S? $S=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-\infty,7+\frac{1}{n}\right]$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, epsilon-delta

I'm trying to find the largest $\epsilon$ such that the
neighborhood centered at $x$ of radius $\epsilon$ is contained in $S$.

That part I think I can do, but I just don't know understand the below set.

$x=-1$

$S=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-\infty,7+\frac{1}{n}\right]$

Comment: Find the intervals $(-\infty,7+1/n]$ for the values $n=1,10,100$ and you'll notice that if a real number $y$ is in $S$, then $y\leq 7$ (i.e. $S = (\infty,7]$). Thus $\epsilon$ is at most $8$.

Comment: @Levent, thanks! but what exactly does the $\bigcap$ mean?  My book introduced this and I've never seen it before.  I know what the $\cap$ when between two sets (the intersection of the sets).

Comment: Well, $\bigcap$ is used for the intersection of a family of sets. If $\{S_x\}_{x\in I}$ is a family of sets with the index set $I$, then $y\in \bigcap_{x\in I} S_x$ if and only if $y\in S_x$ for all $x\in I$.

Comment: @Levent but there doesn't appear to be a family of sets here... am I missing something?

Comment: If you take $A_n = (-\infty, 7+1/n]$ then $S=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n$.

Comment: @Levent so I'm looking for this $\left(-\infty,7+\frac{1}{1}\right]\cap \left(-\infty,7+\frac{1}{2}\right]\cap \left(-\infty,7+\frac{1}{3}\right]\cap ... \left(-\infty,7+\frac{1}{n}\right]$

Comment: @free_mind basically, though there should be a $...$ after $(-\infty,7+1/n]$.